# installshield prerequisites error 7067

Tags: installshield

I have created install project. 
[image]

I used [this tutorail](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/tutorial-adding-setup-prerequisites-to-installshield-package/)

[image]

But when I try to build it, I have [this error 7076](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/ERRDOC/Q206676)

I try to add custom redistributables

- SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi
- dotnetfx35.exe

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, just check this

[image]